# What event could cause a WKWebView inset change when putting phone down?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I've got a WKWebView as a subview in a custom layout in iOS 8.1 and 8.2. Testing on my phone looks great... until I put the phone back down on the table.

It turns out that when the phone gets parallel to the ground, the webview resizes and a ~120px space develops between my webview and navbar. I believe it's the content inset that changes.

What event could cause a WKWebView inset change when putting phone down? I'd love to hook into this event to relayout the subview.

Comment: Are you sure this is happening *inside* the `WKWebView`? It sounds to me that your constraints are not correct. You can test this by changing the background colors of your views. Then it is easy to see if the gap is inside the `WKWebView` or if it happens outside of it because of its placement.

Comment: Thanks for your note. Definitely inside the WKWebView. It turned out I had weird bounds issues that surfaced for "face up" orientation events only.